# how to get remote IP addresses from reverse ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have an Apache webserver running on a local machine through reverse ssh tunnel, i.e.:

ssh -R *:80:local_machine:8080 username@gateway_machine

In other words, all traffic from port 80 on gateway_machine
is sent to port 8080 on local_machine.

For monitoring purposes, I wish to know IP addresses of the remote clients
connected to gateway_machine. However my local Apache server sees
all traffic coming from the IP address of gateway_machine.

My question: Is there any way to setup ssh server running on gateway_machine such that 
it sends all traffic to local_machine with actual remote IP addresses ?

Comment: Try with -v (or -vv or -vvv) and see if the ssh client displays those connections in its log

Comment: good idea thanks. I already persuaded myself that there is no way to do this without "hacking". Though by comparing ssh -vvv debug output with openssh sources I figured out that this happens in 'client_request_forwarded_tcpip()' function defined in clientloop.c. It seems that by default ssh does not forward 'originator_address' (remote client IP) in the TCP/IP header. This could be changed by hacking the sources. I will post the solution here if I get it working

Comment: Can you run something else on the remote machine? For example HAProxy or another Apache HTTPD? In that case you could probably use the remote web proxy to forward from port 80 to say 8080 (remote) and tunnel from 8080 remote to 8080 local. If you do something like this, using an HTTP proxy, you can configure it to include the X-Forwarded-For header with the original IP address.

Answer (score 2):

The SSH protocol uses a channel type called "direct-tcpip" for forwarding a TCP connection. [The protocol message for opening one of these channels](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-7.2) includes the address and port of the client whose connection is being forwarded. So the information that you want is available to the ssh client (which in your case is opening the connection to the target of the forward).

The OpenSSH `ssh` client logs the originator address and port in a debug level message, so you can see it if you run ssh with the `-v` option:

```
$ ssh -v -R 2000:localhost:1000 localhost
...
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 2000, originator ::1 port 51101
```

Here the originator address was ::1 (IPv6 localhost) and port 51101. The `ssh` utility doesn't do anything else with the information.

So, depending on your needs, you have three approaches to collect this information:

1. Invoke the `ssh` process which creates these forwards with the `-v` option, and arrange to collect and parse the relevant debug information.
2. Make [source code](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) changes to `ssh` to make it do what you want it to do with the information.
3. Write your own ssh client which does what you want. SSH client libraries are available for most modern programming languages.